# Find Webservice WSDL from JUDDI

Tags: java, web-services, uddi, juddi

I am new to developing webservices using java. I have an academic project and I developed webservice- Axist2 using Esclipe.
Everything is working fine. And now, i want to publish and find WebService on JUDDI server.
I have followed the tutorial and published the service to juddiv3.
This is result:
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img661/5874/3h8y27.png

And I tried find and query this Webservice published by me , but i can't. Please tell me how to I do it. Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to using the user interface to "find and query" or are you trying to do so programmatically? There's a number of examples both in the client distribution for automated registration and in the documentation. In addition, there's a guide for using the web user interface (juddi-gui).

Without additional details, steps to reproduce the issue, source code, etc, it's difficult to provide an accurate answer

Comment: hi Spy. Thank for your answer.  I really want to combine the user's interface and programmatically. When I publish WS, i want to use GUI, and then when i find this WS, i want to programmatically.

Comment: Ok, so you need some kind of search criteria when searching programmatically. You can search for it by name, key, or a variety of combinations of category and Tmodel instance info. Most use cases use some kind of configurable key or name pattern that can be set or overridden via configuration. There's a number of examples in the juddi-examples/more-uddi-samples project.

Comment: Essentially, you want to call find_service, specifying some search criteria that you know will get you the right records. Or you can call get_serviceDetails using the service key that was registered. Both are on the UDDI inquiry service

Comment: Hi Spy, thanks for your support, i find WS successfully. 
After find this WS, how i cant use service of WebService?
Example this WebService have 3 function: calculator, find location... How do I determine the function needed to use ?

Comment: UDDI can tell you the endpoint of the service to be called and some metadata about it. It's a phone book essentially. It can't tell you how to use a given service, only it's location